# Inbox not working, no results being returned by the XHR

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

The title pretty much says it all. Opened up the page for the first time today, had a shiny red "Oh you got 3 new somethings" indicator, clicked it, and then... emptiness.

First time this happened to me, I found this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67498/the-so-global-inbox-is-empty-sometimes/67506#67506) but it's marked as resolved. Also my last visit to the site was < 10 hours ago.

**Update**

The inbox is working again.

[image]

Comment: `[status-norepro]` on my side.

Comment: I can't see my inbox on my sys

Comment: I'm seeing this in Chrome 9.0.597.98 on Windows XP

Comment: I'm getting this same problem, Inbox empty. Firefox 3 on Windows XP.

Comment: Just FYI, the number you blurred isn't a secret; it just a timestamp acting as a cache breaker. But you're right, better save than sorry :)

Comment: Status-no-longer-repro, seems to be fixed now

Comment: @balpha Yea, wasn't sure about it and had no time to investigate it any further this morning.

Comment: @IvoWetzel If you worked with jQuery ajax you'd know that that's the cache busting query added by jQuery automatically :P

Comment: @YiJiang Sorry but I do real JS :P

Comment: @IvoWetzel Lies! Everyone knows that JavaScript is just code running on a jQuery plugin.

Comment: The inbox has been reset for me yesterday as well.

Comment: I can't reproduce it in Chrome 11.0.672.2 dev.

Comment: I've also seen this; the 'reset' however didn't remove everything, a single comment made a few hours ago which I remember I've seen before everything got wipes is still there, but everything before that is gone

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting this same problem, Inbox empty.  Firefox 3 on Windows XP.  Aaand, it hasn't started working for me, unlike the original poster, so please don't mark this answer as 'accepted' yet.

Comment: **New** items are showing up - I just can see old ones.

Comment: Ditto.  I just got the notification for your reply.

Comment: OK now my inbox isn't showing your reply, either.

Comment: All those who are saying it's fixed... Um, it isn't for me.  In fact, I just came onto stackoverflow.com, had the red circle indicating '1 new notification', and my inbox was completely empty.

Comment: Me too! Same problem here.

Comment: My inbox has apparently started working again, but I wouldn't be surprised if some others weren't.  Seems to be an intermittent problem.